# How do I pin an application to the unity dock when it is always fullscreen?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm running MAME on my Ubuntu desktop, and I'd like to pin it to my launcher. The problem is that MAME always runs in fullscreen with no option to minimize it. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your dash
2. Search for the application
3. Click and drap the icon, drop it on the launcher

[image: Click-and-drag]